# Do I need to use dielectric grease or another type of water proofing in c9 christmas sockets?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I went ahead and took the plunge and ordered the supplies to build my own christmas light strand this year using [this guide](https://www.christmaslightsetc.com/pages/How-to-Splice-Wires-for-Custom-Christmas-Lights.htm). I built a test strip, and I'm realizing that water intrusion into the c9 socket looks super duper easy.

Is it standard practice to use dielectric grease or something similar? I imagine dielectric would be an awful mess, but don't exactly want to wrap every single christmas light in electrical tape either.

Comment: Dielectric grease is for anti corrosion not water proofing. Water proofing you christmas tree lights? Are they for an indoor tree or for outdoor decor?

Comment: If the lights are rated for outdoor use, I wouldn't worry about it.  If they aren't, then I wouldn't ever use them that way.

Comment: @Duston Duh, I hadn't even thought to check for indoor/outdoor use; since everything I'm reading is focused around outdoor christmas light displays I just assumed. I double checked and everything is outdoor rated.. Thank you!

Comment: I would not trust those cheap spike penetrating Zip connectors to be any kind of water resistant.

Comment: Are all these components UL listed?  If not, back they go.  Lots of people shipping unsafe crud from China.  If it arrives from east Asia or from an Amazon warehouse, assume it's fake and look closely for the UL or CSA mark.  CE is NOT a valid mark, it's what they use to fake it when they can't get a proper mark.

Comment: Well to be clear, CE is just a DIFFERENT labeling issue. Yes it has NOTHING to do with UL, nor is it really a statement about safety. CE is "self certified", meaning the manufacturer applies the label based on their own claims of the device meeting minimum international standards. Some reputable manufacturers take it seriously, but basically it can be like the foxes certifying that the henhouse is secure... I consider it meaningless, but it's technically not "fake".